# Play video on surfaceview while another Thread do some calculations on different Surface - Android

Tags: android, multithreading

In my app i want to do some calculations on video file in separate thread(not on main)  and in the middle of the test i want to preview another video.

This is a part of my code :

```
public class SampleTestingAlgorithmAct extends Activity {

Intent intentTestResults;

private static final String TAG = "Decoder";
private DecoderThread mThread = null;
Date startTime, endTime;
GlobalVarClass GVC;

int Frame_Size = 100, Frame_Size_ROI = 5;//600,30
String SCR = "", Velocity = "", VSCR = "", ROI = "", MSC = "", ROI_X = "", ROI_Y = ""; 

boolean Finished = false, StopCamera = false;
String VIDEO_PATH = "", VIDEO_PATH_TMP = "";

VideoView videoview;
MediaController mediaController;

ProgressBar PB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_testing_algorithm);

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    intentTestResults = new Intent(this, TestResultsAct.class);

     GVC = ((GlobalVarClass) getApplicationContext());

     VIDEO_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Frames/" + GVC.getFileForPreview();
     VIDEO_PATH_TMP = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Frames/" + GVC.getTempFileForPreview();

    videoview = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Videoview);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);

    PB = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarTest);
    PB.bringToFront();
    PB.setFocusable(true);

    StartTest();
}

private void StartTest() {

    startTime = new Date();
    mThread = null;
    mThread = new DecoderThread( null, VIDEO_PATH, Frame_Size, Frame_Size_ROI);
    mThread.dumpStack();
    mThread.start();

    final Timer myTimer1 = new Timer();

    myTimer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!Finished)
                        {
                            if(mThread.outputSurface != null)
                            {
                                ROI = "( " + String.format("%.0f",mThread.outputSurface.OUTcropCenter_C) + "," + String.format("%.0f",mThread.outputSurface.OUTcropCenter_R) + " )";
                                ROI_X = String.format("%.0f",mThread.outputSurface.OUTcropCenter_C);
                                ROI_Y = String.format("%.0f",mThread.outputSurface.OUTcropCenter_R);
                                SCR = String.format("%.3f",mThread.outputSurface.SCR);
                                MSC = String.format("%.3f",mThread.outputSurface.MSC);
                                Velocity = String.format("%.3f",mThread.outputSurface.Velocity);
                                VSCR = String.format("%.3f",mThread.outputSurface.VSCR);
                                if( !VSCR.equals("0.000")  & !SCR.equals("0.000") & !MSC.equals("0.000") & !Velocity.equals("0.000") &! VSCR.equals("") & !SCR.equals("") & !MSC.equals("") & !Velocity.equals(""))
                                {
                                    WriteToXMLFile();
                                    SaveKeyParameters();
                                    endTime = new Date();
                                    Finished = true;
                                }
                                if( !ROI.equals("( 0,0 )")  & !ROI.equals("") & !StopCamera)
                                {
                                    StopCamera = true;

                                    Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(VIDEO_PATH_TMP);
                                    videoview.setVideoURI(videoURI);
                                    videoview.requestFocus();
                                    videoview.start();
                                }
                                    PB.setMax(Frame_Size + Frame_Size_ROI + 2);

                                if(!Finished)
                                    PB.setProgress(mThread.counter);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            });
        if(Finished)
            {
                PB.setProgress(0);
                System.gc();

                myTimer1.cancel();
                myTimer1.purge();



            }
        }
    }, 1000,10); 

}
```

mThread  is  a class the extended Thread. and after first part of calculation I want to play the Video.

(**private class DecoderThread extends Thread {**)
But I've got this message on the device :

**"Can't play this video"**

If I don't start the Thread (mThread.Start()) the video is playing normally.

How can I fix it ?

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**
This is the logcat:

```
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/OMX(1938):  setParam  sum(4147200) > max resolution(3010560)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/ACodec(24626):  configureCodec multi window instance fail  appPid : 24626
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346): readBundle: bad magic number
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346): readBundle: trace = java.lang.RuntimeException
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at android.os.Bundle.readFromParcelInner(Bundle.java:1677)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:83)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1579)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1564)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:371)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/Bundle(2346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/ACodec(24626): [OMX.SEC.avc.dec] configureCodec returning error -38
03-12 10:08:23.800: E/MediaCodec(24626): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -38)
03-12 10:08:29.700: E/Watchdog(2346): !@Sync 221
03-12 10:08:32.225: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2555): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-12 10:08:32.235: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2555): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-12 10:08:32.245: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2555): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-12 10:08:32.710: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2555): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-12 10:08:33.155: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2346): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-12 10:08:33.750: E/OMXNodeInstance(1938): !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
03-12 10:08:33.750: E/InputDispatcher(2346): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-12 10:08:33.750: E/InputDispatcher(2346): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-12 10:08:33.750: E/InputDispatcher(2346): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-12 10:08:33.775: E/WFDService(2346): FHD : android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP
```

Comment: setParam  sum(4147200) > max resolution(3010560), anyone know how they calculate the max resolution? I met the same issue too.